# How to order the Admin Views in a custom Component?

Tags: joomla2.5

Not new to Joomla, but new to 2.5, and am using Cook Component Builder to get my feet wet (it's quite nice!).  Anyways, I've created 3 tables/Controllers and matching views.

The problem is that they appear as tabs and menu items in the order I created them, but i'd like them to appear in a more logical way for the user.  I'm past the point of using Cook, but cannot determine where in the core Joomla code this is determined.  Presumably my generated code is missing something, and Joomla is using some default, and after *several hours of tracing* (I've done my homework, but can't *find* the code to show what I would have tried) what Joomla is doing, I'm still unable to find where/what I should change to alter the order that they appear.

e.g., in the Article Manager, the 3 tabs are :

```
| Articles | Categories | Featured Articles |
```

Where is that sequence of tables determined, or how would I change that ordering to this?:

```
| Articles | Featured Articles | Categories |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Article manager (com_content) has a helper which generates the links (called submenu).

Have a look inside *helpers* directory, inside content.php.

Inside the class called *ContentHelper*, you will find the function *addSubmenu()*. This is the function responsible to generating the menu.

So the order will change if you put the *JSubMenuHelper::addEntry* calls in the desired order.

Got it? :)